# Why does this sentence have a positive tag?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, question-tags, negative-polarity-items

This question ends with *is he*:

> He is seldom absent, is he?

Shouldn't it be *isn't he*? Please explain.

---

**Edit note:**

This question below does not address the issue here:

[An appropriate question tag for "He's too weak to walk."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226507/an-appropriate-question-tag-for-hes-too-weak-to-walk)

Comment: In case it's not clear, the sentence cited above is valid. A lot depends on intonation and the message the speaker wants to convey. In the phrase: "It's a beautiful day, is it?" The tag **is it** is positive. The speaker seems to be challenging the listener to confirm the statement. In "It's a beautiful day, isn't it?" the tag **isn't it** is negative. Here the speaker is asking for confirmation that the day *is* beautiful.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The real answer about why this has a positive tag is explained in my answer below!

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule of thumb, positive clauses tend to take negative question tags, and negative clauses tend to take positive tags.

Note, however, the use of the term clauses. The negative polarity of a clause can be caused by other negative words apart from *not*. For example, these words with negative meanings will all give a clause negative polarity:

- *few, little, seldom, never, rarely*

Because of this, clauses using these items will tend to take positive tags:

- Few people have ever actually finished it, have they?
- There's little chance of that ever happening, is there?
- Whales seldom attack humans, do they?
- You've never actually read the book, have you?
- Elephants rarely forget a face, do they?

Notice as well that negative clauses attract  what are known as Negative Polarity Items. These are words (that often have positive meanings) which tend to occur in negative clauses (and often occur in questions and conditional antecedents). Here are a few of these items:

- any, ever, yet, at all

We can see from the following data that clauses with *seldom* pattern like clauses with *not*:

- *He has any time. (ungrammatical)
- He seldom has any time.
- He does not have any time.

and:

- *He has ever been on time.  (ungrammatical<sup>1</sup>)
- He has seldom ever been on time.
- He has not ever been on time.

also:

- *Whenever I ask him to hand the work in, he has finished it yet.  (ungrammatical)
- Whenever I ask him to hand the work in, he has seldom finished it yet.
- Whenever I ask him to hand the work in, he has not finished it yet.

and lastly:

- *She goes to work at all.  (ungrammatical)
- She seldom goes to work at all.
- She doesn't go to work at all.

We can see then that the reason that the original poster's example has a positive question tag, is that the main clause is negative because of the presence of the word *seldom*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>But see Edwin Ashworth's comment about archaic positive *ever* in the comments below.</sup>

Comment: This has just resurfaced. IMO a fine answer. Playing, as ever, devil's advocate, I'd better point out that 'He has ever been on time. (ungrammatical)' is made grammatical (though in this instance arguably unacceptably incongruous, with clashing styles) if say Tolkien uses it (an archaic, literary usage). 'Simbelmyne. Ever has it grown on the tombs of my forebears.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed. I've added a footnote referring to your comment. (and remembered to save it, this time!)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Check out this sentence:

> He has never gone to England, has he?

In tag questions, the second sentence opposes the whole meaning of the first one, not just the grammar.

Answer (score -2):

This is correct if the speaker wants to confirm unexpected information:
"Did I hear you say that he is seldom absent?"

'He is seldom absent, isn't he?' suggests that you already know that he is seldom absent and the person you are talking to needs to be persuaded.

Comment: For positive questions with positive speech tags, this answer is correct. But this isn't what negative sentences with negative speech tags mean. In fact, they don't mean anything, they just sound weird.